# How can I use geom_text to add text at top of each box in a box plot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a box plot with text annotation at the top of each box (some boxes are not tall enough for the legend to represent them) but I end up having the text at the top and bottom of each box.

[image]

R version 4.0.0
Windows 7
Here is a sample data and code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 24
dat2 <- data.frame( 
                  Treatment=rep(c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6"), 2),
                  Time=rep(c("Initial", "Final"), n/2),
                  Count=sample(20:300, n))
require(plyr)
require(magrittr)
dat2<-as.data.frame(dat)
dat2=
mutate(dat2,
Time=factor(Time, levels=unique(Time)))
p2.dat<-ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x = Treatment, y = Count)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Time), width = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 1))
p2.dat + geom_text(aes(label = paste(Time)), position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5, size = 4, stat = "unique", parse = TRUE)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can summarise your data for `geom_text` to have maximum value of `Count`:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(y = Count, fill = Time), 
    width = 0.8, 
    position = position_dodge2(width = 1)
  ) +  
  geom_text(
    data = dat2 %>% group_by(Treatment, Time) %>% summarise(y = max(Count), Time = first(Time)),
    aes(y = y,label = Time), 
    position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
    vjust = -0.5, 
    size = 4, 
    stat = "unique", 
    parse = TRUE
  )
```

This will plot text above maximum value (which can be 'outlier').

[image]

If you want to put text above end of upper whisker replace data in `geom_text` with:

```
dat2 %>% group_by(Treatment, Time) %>% summarise(
  y = min(max(Count), diff(quantile(Count, probs = c(0.25, 0.75)) * c(3/2, 5/2))), 
  Time = first(Time)
)
```

In this example both methods will work because there are no 'outliers' in data.

Comment: Thank you @det for the response. However, your graph did not show the Treatment, Time grouping for each boxplot. I tried running it but the Final and Initial text appeared on the same point making it double print at the top of the highest value box.

Comment: I don't have those problems, can you please share ggplot2 version and data on which you don't get wanted plot?

Comment: ggplot2 version 3.3.3, data is same as initially posted. I get this information: summarise()` has grouped output by 'Treatment'. You can override using the `.groups` argument

Comment: Yeah, summarise drops last group that's just reminding message. Plot should be just fine.

Comment: You can try and add `ungroup`  after `summarise` if you get unexpected output (I have `3.3.2` version).

Comment: Thanks once again @det. The behaviour in question looks like this: [link](https://imgur.com/jn2HM6B) I feel the issue comes from this line of code: `data = dat2 %>% group_by(Treatment, Time) %>% summarise(y = max(Count), Time = first(Time))` particularly the part: `summarise(y = max(Count)`